# Move a batch of files one at a time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Writing a linux script to move files from one folder to another. However it needs to first display the properties of the file e.g. size, date created, name etc and then ask the user if they want to copy it.

I can batch copy, but not sure how to view properties of one file then ask user if they want to copy it, then move onto the next file in the folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I would copy the code i've already done, however none of it is relevant to the question, i've so far made it process the two folder arguments (source and destination) and create a destination folder if the one specified does not exist.

To summarise:

- Program copies files from a folder to another one by one
- For each file the properties need to be displayed
- Then the user is asked if he/she wants the file to be copied
- File copied, then move onto the next file (guessing the number of files in the folder can be counted using a built in bash argument)

Thanks!

Connor

Comment: SO is not a free coding service

Comment: [batch-file] is exclusively for Windows scripting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will work:

```
dir=$1
newdir=$2
for file in $dir/*
do
    filesize=$(stat -f%z $file)   # stat command finds size of file in bytes
    filename=$(basename $file)
    echo "Name of file: $filename"
    echo "File size: $filesize bytes"
    ls -l $file     #shows permisions, parent directory, last modification date...
    read -r -p "Would you like to copy file?:" answer
    if [[ $answer =~ ^(yes|y| ) ]]  # checks possible user entries
    then
        cp $file $newdir/$filename  #copies file from original dir to new dir
    else
        echo "file not copied"
    fi
done
```

For the `read` command, which reads in the user input, here's a description of it taken from the man page:

```
-p prompt
    Display prompt, without a trailing newline, before attempting
    to read any input. The prompt is displayed only if input is coming from a
    terminal.

-r   
    If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character.
    The backslash is considered to be part of the line. In particular, a backslash-newline
    pair may not be used as a line continuation.
```

The script is run as so:

```
./script original new
```

Where `original` is directory to be read, and `new` is the directory where you want your files to be copied to.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The [Dialog](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) command is your friend. Instead of trying to "get" the file attributes, just use `ls -al '$filename'`